# INDEX & MATCH Functions With Wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to return values from column A in the second workbook into the first. I'm using a combination of the INDEX and MATCH functions and this works well on exact matches. However I need to match any or part of the lookup values in the lookup array. I thought of using wildcards in the lookup argument of the MATCH function but it doesn't give me the desired result.

Example of data...

WB1...

A1, `=INDEX(WB2!$A:$A,MATCH("*"&B1&"*",WB2!$B:$B,0))`
B1, `Standard Access Enclosure Fitted For (dual supply)`

WB2...

A12, `AP50100467`
B12, `Standard Access "Fitted For" Enclosure (dual supply)`

The formula in WB1 A1 returns "N/A" as it's not an exact match even with the wildcard. Would appreciate any help with modifying the existing formula or perhaps there's another way?

Thank you

Comment: The wild card does not mean an approximate match.  it is saying look for `x` anywhere in the string. for example `"*"&"bye"&"*"` will match on `Goodbye` but not `Goodbey`  The full string in `B1` must match ***exactly*** a part of the string in the other workbook `B1`

Comment: You are searching first cell that **contains** the text `Standard Access Enclosure Fitted For (dual supply)`. The value in B12 is `Standard Access "Fitted For" Enclosure (dual supply)`. This means B12 **does not** contain B1, so MATCH returns nothing

Comment: Ok, I understand. How can I match the values in WB1 B1, WB2 B12 and return the value in A12?

Comment: You say `I need to match any or part of the lookup values` but not detailed, 1 character, 1 word, 2 words ... how many are called matches?

Comment: Both strings contain the same words but in a different order and Fitted For is quoted in B12 but not in B1. I suppose you could weight it with a percentage of match? If greater the 95% match then return the value in column A. I'm not sure how else you could determine if it's a close match?

Comment: Perhaps this add-in helps: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011

Comment: @jkpieterse thank you. Unfortunately I'm in a domain and don't have adminstrative privileges to install software. Our IT dept would seriously frown upon the use of add-ins, even those by Microsoft!

Comment: Pity, there are such outstanding tools available if only your IT dept would be wise enough to allow them :-)